# How to configure QOS on thomson speedtouch TG585 v7

Tags: qos

[image]    http://speedtouch.lan/ is very limited, I can only do stupid stuff with no real control over the router, I can't throttle my WiFi speed and I there's no option for QoS, I only managed to use Parental Control, to block the websites that I want to block, but other than that there's no real option concerning bandwidth control of QoS settings, what can I do about it?

Comment: Are you using the latest firmware?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot configure QoS on the TG585v7 from the web GUI. It can be done through the command line interface though (connect using telnet). Note that it is not exactly easy.

You may find the CLI guide for the [TG585v7 here](http://www.technicolorbroadbandpartner.com/dsl-modems-gateways/products/product-detail.php?id=161&seg=3).

Answer (score 1):

I've just configured QoS thought the command line after finding a [much less obtuse guide for QoS on Thomson TG587 routers at http://npr.me.uk/ipqos.html](http://npr.me.uk/ipqos.html). Hope you find it as useful I as just have.

Please note though, QoS on these routers seem to be just MAC based - not protocol based.